# component prop missing from any mui interface even though it works

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using Material ui (mui) v5.

I am creating a custom component called `CustomTab`.

```
import { Tab, type TabProps } from '@mui/material'

interface CustomTabProps extends TabProps {}

function CustomTab (props: CustomTabProps){
  return <Tab {...props} />
}
```

This component works well, with react and typescript. however, when I consume it, I want to use the `component` prop on it, **which do exist on the original `Tab` component**.

```
<CustomTab label="hi" value="3" component={Link} to="/xxx" />
```

it complains that the component prop is missing from the type CustomTabProps.

OK, this is legit, I want to know, what is the type which I should use instead of `TabProps` in order to make it identical to the original `Tab` component? I want to see the `component` prop exists on my `CustomTab` component.

So what is the correct type I should pick up from `@mui/material` here?

Thanks.